# Pandas and Numpy missing from path - Python/Pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, path

I have a fully functioning jupyter notebook (.ipynb) file that can find and import both pandas and numpy.  I also have that same exact code saved as a .py file in the same exact folder.

When I try to run the .py file with VSCode or Python Shell, I get an error message saying that numpy and pandas can't be found and aren't on path.

Not sure how the .ipynb file right next to it can find these modules but the .py file can't.

Any help would be much appreciated.  (The .ipynb file runs through anaconda)

Comment: "Not sure how the .ipynb file right next to it can find these modules but the .py file can't." Because that's not really relevant. You aren't using the same interpreter/environment as your Jupyter kernel. Look up how to set up your VSCode interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are hosting jupyter notebook from conda it can easily use the same environment and able to find the pandas and numpy. Try import the same py file in jupyter notebook you will be able to execute the code. You need to specify python path to environment variables which is pointing towards the one which jupyter is pointing.